# Proc SQL assignment of missing values

Tags: sas, proc-sql

If I run a query that produces zero rows, I still want a SAS dataset created with one row having all columns with missing values assigned.

I found a way to do this using a separate data step:

```
%let dsid   = %sysfunc (open(myfile));
%let anyobs = %sysfunc (attrn(&dsid,ANY));
%let dsid   = %sysfunc (close(&dsid));
data _null_;
  if &anyobs=0 then do;
     call execute('data work.myfile; call missing(col1, col2, col3); run;');
end;
```

This works fine but i was wondering if there a way to assign missing for each column within proc sql?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's say you execute this:

```
proc sql;
  create table class as 
    select * from sashelp.class 
    where age=19;
quit;
```

Then you could just do this:

```
%macro ifMissingRow(data=);
  %let dsid   = %sysfunc (open(&data.));
  %let anyobs = %sysfunc (attrn(&dsid,ANY));
  %let dsid   = %sysfunc (close(&dsid));
  %if &anyobs=0 %then %do;
    data &data.;
      output;
      set &data.;
    run;
  %end;
%mend ifmissingRow;

%ifMissingRow(data=class);
```

Output is before set in order to get the row before SET stops the data step with 0 row (h/t Tom for the pointer).

Comment: Excellent solution.  Thank you!

Comment: If you already know there are no observations then no need for the IF 0 trick. Just move the OUTPUT statement before the SET statement and you will get one observation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a easy method using the `NOBS=` option of the `SET` statement to insure that your dataset has at least one observation.

```
data want ;
  if 0=_nobs then output;
  set want nobs=_nobs;
run;
```

Note if the dataset is large and you did not want to have to re-write the data then you might use some method to conditionally generate the data step.  For example you could test the automatic macro variable `SQLOBS` and if it is 0 then generate a data step.  In this case no need to test the nobs since you already did.  Also you could use the automatic macro variable `SYSLAST` instead of hard coding the dataset name.  You could use CALL EXECUTE for this, but you could also just use `IFC()` function.

```
%sysfunc(dequote(
 %sysfunc(ifc(0=&sqlobs,'data &syslast;output;set &syslast;run;',''))
))
```

**Of perhaps best of all use the `MODIFY` statement and conditionally run an `OUTPUT` statement.**  You could test the `SQLOBS` macro variable.

```
data &syslast ;
  if &sqlobs=0 then output;
  modify &syslast ;
  stop;
run;
```

or you could use `NOBS=` option the MODIFY statement.

```
data &syslast ;
  if 0=_nobs then output;
  modify &syslast nobs=_nobs;
  stop;
run;
```

**All SQL solution**

If you know at least one of the variable names then you can use and SQL insert statement.

```
insert into &syslast (varname) values (null);
```

So you might make a simple macro that takes Dataset Name, Number of Observations and a variable name as input.

```
%macro ifzeronull(dsn,nobs,avar);
%if &nobs=0 %then %do;
  insert into &dsn (&avar) values (null);
%end;
%mend ;
```

Then you can stay in the same PROC SQL call and conditionally add the observation.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
    select * from sashelp.class
    where age=19
  ;
  %ifzeronull(&syslast,&sqlobs,name)
quit;
```

Comment: Nice survey of the options!